# ServiceStack Validation and Input fields Repopulation

Tags: servicestack

When Using FluentValidation through ServiceStack, what is the technique for retrieving previous form values when validation fails?

I need this data so that I can repopulate the fields that passed validation. As it stands now, if a user types in one thing wrong, everything on the form is gone and they must re-type everything over again.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thank you.